# POSTING json with nested objects to server

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

This is my first native iOS app, so please bear with..

How would I construct this json data in a NSDictionary (I would guess thats how I would do it) so I cand make it part of my request body.

```
    {
        "Properties":{
           "Description":"String content",
           "Domain":"String content",
           "GroupID":"String content", 
           ...
       },
       "Foo":{....},
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a dictionary, created using literals or code.

```
NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"Properties":@{@"Description":@"String content",@"Domain":@"String content",@"GroupID":@"String content",},@"Foo":{....},}
```

Convert the dictionary into JSON data ready for posting.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Thats pretty awesome! I was expecting something much more complicated :-) LEt me do this